# Without using lambda how can I neatly create a function given an expression?

Tags: c++

Would like to be able to do something like

```
std::map<EventType, boost::function<bool(int,int)>  callbackMap;
callbackMap[EVENT1] = boost::bind( magic_creator( this->m_isHerp && !this->m_isDerp ) , _1, _2 );
```

basically give an expression that evaluates to true or false to the magic_creator and it returns a function to which I can bind with boost. So in the above case, the magic_creator would create a function that would return true regardless of _1 and _2. I am not able to use lamdas as it is not avail to me. Anyone got anything for this?

P.S Assume callbackMap is part of some class and so is the current scope of the above code.

Comment: If you could do that easily and neatly, we wouldn't have *needed* to add Lambdas to the language.

Comment: I was hoping there was a small solution with template magic, as this is just a small subset of lamdas

Comment: "*the magic_creator would create a function that would return true regardless of _1 and _2.*" Wait; are you saying that you need a functor that just returns a value given at construction time?

Comment: @NicolBolas not quite, because it needs to evaluate the "this->m_isHerp && !this->m_isDerp" expression, and based on that just returns whatever that expression yields

Comment: "this->m_isHerp && !this->m_isDerp" After you make the reddit 'Lambda Rage' rage comic, can you post the link here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually possible and not *that* ugly with either the [Boost Lambda Library](http://www.boost.org/libs/lambda/), [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/libs/bind/bind.html) or [Boost.Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/phoenix/)'s [`bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/composite.html#phoenix.composite.bind).

All placeholders and binder types returned from a call to `bind` from any of those libraries will have all kinds of operators overloaded so you can easily create expressions with them "on the fly". With Boost.Bind:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

struct X{ bool a, b; };

int main(){
  using boost::bind;
  auto op = bind(&X::a, _1) && !bind(&X::b, _1);
  X x{true, false};
  auto test = bind(op, x);
  if(test())
    std::cout << "Yay\n";
}
```

[Live example.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/add3187bebb79c8d42ba40d6748bcfa3)

This, of course, has the obvious disadvantage of going through member pointers. Also, in C++03, you had a mighty problem writing out the type of such a "lambda", since it's a huge templated mess. The little example above will yield a huge name, as can be seen [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/90be9bbfaa890856e10ecc598714f1df). And since a library solution was not "the best it could be", the standard committee added lambdas to the language. Yay.

Note that, while C++11's `std::bind` looks similar on the surface, it's a *pure binder*. It does not allow you to create expressions on-the-fly as it does not overload any operators for any related types.